# React-router-dom showing blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am trying to figure out React and am not sure what is wrong here, as the browser shows a blank.

Here is the Code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}/>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
  }
  
export default App;
```

Update 1 -

[image: console error]

The code as viewed on index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: Is there any error displayed on the browser console?

Comment: There are no errors here. I think it can be due to  ```<Home/>```

Comment: I have updated with a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `react@18` change in how React apps are rendered. `createRoot` takes a DOMNode reference, not JSX. Once the root is created, ***then*** you can call a `render` method on it.

Example:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

See [`react-dom-client`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html) for more in-depth detail.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me learn. I finally understand the issue.

Comment: this breaks react-quill

Comment: @nrmad And how is this `react` or `react-dom`'s fault? If you've an issue specific to `react-quill` I suggest filing an issue with their repo. You could also ask a new, specific post on SO regarding using `react-quill` and `react@18`, and reference this post. Feel free to ping me here with a link to your question and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Just trying to prevent anyone else from losing time.  Lots of breaking changes in 18

Comment: @nrmad Well, it *is* a major version change, so breaking changes shouldn't be unexpected. That said, I've not run into to too many breaking issues between React 17 and 18, the React team typically goes above and beyond to ensure smooth version transitions. If there are issues it's typically going to be in other React libraries you are consuming. The React team can't help what 3rd-party library maintainers do with their code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any error in this page. Check whether you have imported the home component properly here. If it is imported properly, Check the home component for errors. You can also check whether you are getting any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: `const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);`. Use react dom like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, I don't think the issue here is with the Home component, I have previously run it error free. It's only when I wrap it around the Router that things get wild.

Comment: Can you share the version of react js you are using ?

Comment: Also, using the provided code generates more errors than it resolves, not sure if we are looking at the right cause.

Comment: React js version ??

Comment: the version is - 18.1.0

Comment: `import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./routes/About'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);`. Use routing like this.

Comment: I think we are getting close, the error shows on the screen, Error: Can't resolve "./routes/Home" and similar with About. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just change the component location alone. In your case it is not './routes/Home'. It is './Home'. So change it to const Home = lazy(() => import('./Home')); and remove About line.